# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'countryid' not found

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**It is my java method which i am using it for updating the user**
**at the backend i am using jdbc not jdbc template for updating the user
i am unable to insert the countryid as the error is showing no countryid column name is found. the error are showing that the counrtyid is missing but in my sql editor is have seen the query is correct to the level**

```
 public User updateUsers(int id) throws SQLException {
    User user = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    int active = 0;
    try {
        con = createConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(
                " select UserMaster1.usermasterid,UserMaster1.FName,UserMaster1.LName,UserMaster1.Gender,UserMaster1.address,UserLogin.Email,UserLogin.Password,UserMaster1.MobileNo,country.countryname,s.state,UserMaster1.hobby "
                        + " from UserMaster1 " 
                        + " INNER JOIN country  ON UserMaster1.country=country.countryid "
                        + " INNER JOIN state as s ON UserMaster1.state=s.stateid "
                        + " INNER join hobbyMaster ON UserMaster1.hobby=hobbyMaster.HobbyId "
                        + " INNER join UserLogin ON UserMaster1.usermasterid=UserLogin.usermasterid "
                        + " where UserMaster1.usermasterid=? ");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("usermasterid"));
            user.setFname(rs.getString("FName"));
            user.setLname(rs.getString("LName"));
            user.setGender(rs.getString("Gender"));
            user.setEmail(rs.getString("Email"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
            user.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));
            user.setMobile_no(rs.getInt("MobileNo"));
            user.setCountry(rs.getString("countryid"));
            user.setState(rs.getString("stateid"));
            user.setHobby(rs.getInt("hobby"));
        }
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

`it is returning the user from the method at the technology side i am using spring-mvc i suppose it is not of the concern`

**It is the error which the code is showing to me on executing.**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'countryid' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5212)
at in.co.xomic.dao.HomeDataAcessOperation.updateUsers(HomeDataAcessOperation.java:237)
at in.co.xomic.service.HomeService.updateUserById(HomeService.java:60)
at in.co.xomic.controller.HomeController.updateUser(HomeController.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you get value via `rs.getString("countryid")` but you did not select it in your sql

To solve it you need to add `country.country.id` in your select:

```
select UserMaster1.usermasterid,UserMaster1.FName,UserMaster1.LName,
 UserMaster1.Gender,UserMaster1.address,UserLogin.Email,
UserLogin.Password,UserMaster1.MobileNo,country.countryname,
s.state,UserMaster1.hobby,country.countryid,s.stateid
```

Comment: because you have add country name in your sql block so that you can show it in jsp page

Comment: do you still get the same error? or the country.countryid is null?

Comment: cheers i just did it.thanks for your help.there was some change which i did i am correcting.just because you don't know my column names this has happend not your cause totally mine and you gave 100% for it.